# EntityManager.find() SQL Injection safe

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, checkmarx

Is the EntityManager.find() SQL injection safe?
I have this codes and Checkmarx complaining on SQL Injection.

```
`public T find(ID id) {
    return entityManager.find(persistentClass, id); 
}`
```

EntityManager.find() expeting this doing parameterized statement on the id. example: "Select * from Process where id = ?"